# How does tidal locking work if planets are almost perfect spheres?

Tags: tidal-effect

I guess this question has more to do with orders of magnitude than actual theory but as I understand, planets like mercury are almost perfect spheres with very minor deviations. For instance, Wikipedia lists the flattening of mercury as $0.0000$ (this is four significant digits I believe). How then is tidal locking even possible?

Comment: Because of the word 'almost'.

Answer (score 0):

A few points to clear this up:

1. Mercury is **not** tidally locked. It has a 3:2 spin resonance with the sun, which is due to a similar mechanism, but not the same thing. As you suggest, Mercury's flatness contributes to it not being tidally locked despite it living in such a strong gravitational differential for billions of years.
2. Not all flatness is created equal. Though the Earth has a higher flatness coefficient, this is entirely due to the Earth's spin and bulging at the equator. Bulging at the equator does not contribute to tidal locking. A planet can have a much lower flatness coefficient and being much more susceptible to tidal locking if its asymmetry is azimuthal.
3. In general, it is azimuthal asymmetry, strong gravitational differential, time, and fluidity of a planet's composition that contributes to tidal locking. Gravitational differential can also contribute to azimuthal asymmetry - as the Earth's field did to the moon. That's part of why the moon is tidally locked to the earth.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the flattening, which is the name for the deformation associated with the angular velocity of the celestial body with respect to its own center of mass.

In the case of the Earth this flattening gives rise to gyroscopic precession; for the Earth this is referred as 'the precession of the equinoxes'.

This flattening, and the resultant gyroscopic precession, are *unrelated* to the phenomenon of tidal lock.

The inner moons of Jupiter are tidally locked.

In the case of the moons of Jupiter the gravitational effect of the moons on Jupiter is negligable, even on the time scale of the solar system's lifetime. So that simplifies the physics; only the effect of Jupiter on the moons needs to be accounted for.

In the final state of being tidally locked the moon is deformed in the following way: instead of being spherical the moon is elongated, like a [rugby ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_ball) is elongated. The line of elongation point towards Jupiter

If the orbit of the moon would be perfectly circular (which in fact it isn't) then in the final state of tidal lock there are no shear forces inside the moon.

But before reaching that state of tidal lock the moon was continuously kneaded by Jupiter. This process is very similar to kneading dough. Dough that is being kneaded warms up. That warming is not only from the kneader's hands, it is also from the dough internally rubbing against itself.

Before becoming tidally locked the process of being kneaded (by Jupiter) is changing the angular velocity of the Moon. Usually the starting state is that the spin angular velocity of the moon is larger than the orbital angular velocity of the moon. The process of tidal kneading dissipates rotational kinetic energy, slowing down the spin angular velocity of the moon.

The above is in fact relevant for assessing what is going on with Mercury. If Mercury would have any kind of internal fluidity then there would be opportunity for the Sun to cause kneading of Mercury, and spin angular velocity would keep decreasing.

However, the 2:3 resonance between the spin angular velocity of Mercury and the orbital velocity of Mercury suggests that there is only a negligable amount of dissipation of Mercury rotational kinetic energy.

In order for the 2:3 resonance to happen at all the planet Mercury must be somewhat elongated (rugby ball shaped). In order for the resonance to be a sustained resonance this elongation must have a fixed orientation with respect Mercury itself.